# How to edit Sidebar of wordpress site

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a blog recently I have used some third-party ad serving network they have given code to post on the website but when I am using it in the sidebar the image is not set with the background image.
Please check the [website](https://www.techsniff.in) and look for Sidebar ad images.

**Wordpress theme Revenue-pro**

There is no error till now but when i am using the ad code the image sizes are not fitting with the sidebar image.

Comment: It's not related to the theme, it's related to the third-party ads provider. You can Add custom css to resize the iframe in your page, but that will cut a part of the ad image.

Comment: In your `div-outer-2140`, you have **width: 300px;** , change this to : **width: 100%;**

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can not control the content of the ad itself. It looks like the best you can do is change `div-outer-2140` to have `width: 100%;`. 
This will cut off part of the ad, but it will fit what you are trying to accomplish. I can't seem to find a better solution at the moment.